# How to read a ledger file of a local Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have already start a local Fabric network 2.2 by following the [official guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/release-2.2/write_first_app.html) (**fabcar project**).
This is the output of `docker ps -a`:
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HDMR.png)

Now, I have these questions:

1. Where is the ledger file which stores the transaction history?
2. How can I see the historical transactions and the created blocks?

I have read the doc in Fabric Website, that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ledger data is under `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData` inside your peer container. You might have `/var/hyperledger/production` mapped to a volume to save your peer state. When using CouchDB to store world state, the world state is stored in the CouchDB container (under something like `/opt/couchdb/data`, which might be mapped to a volume, too).
2. In my opinion, the easiest way is to deploy Hyperledger Explorer for your network: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/main/README.md.